# Outlook Contacts API - Paging Results

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts

I'm trying to display ALL the Outlook contacts for a selected account.  When an account has a few thousand contacts, the following code only shows the first n contacts.  The contactResults object has a MorePagesAvailable property and a             GetNextPageAsync() method available, but I clearly do NOT know how to use them.  Can someone please enlighten me.

```
string token = (string)Session["access_token"];
string email = (string)Session["user_email"];

// Since we have the token locally from the Session, just return it here
OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), async () => { return token; });

client.Context.SendingRequest2 += new EventHandler<SendingRequest2EventArgs>((sender, e) => InsertXAnchorMailboxHeader(sender, e, email));

var contactResults = await client.Me.Contacts
                    .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayName)
                    .Take(2500)
                    .Select(c => new DisplayContact(c))
                    .ExecuteAsync();

foreach (DisplayContact displayContact in contactResults.CurrentPage)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(displayContact);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactResults = await client.Me.Contacts
                .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayName)
                .Select(c => new DisplayContact(c))
                .ExecuteAsync();

while (true)
{
    foreach (DisplayContact displayContact in contactResults.CurrentPage)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(displayContact);

    if (contactResults.MorePagesAvailable)
        contactResults = await contactResults.GetNextPageAsync();
    else
        break;
}
```